# Is the main() function re-entrant?

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point, reentrancy

I heard that in C, main() is reentrant, while in C++ is not.

Is this true? What is the scenario of re-entering the main() function?

Comment: I don't think you mean [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). It is true however that you are allowed to call `main` in C and you are not allowed to call it in C++.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Early C++ implementations, which were based on translation to C, implemented global constructors via adding a function call to the beginning of `main`. Under such an implementation, calling `main` again would re-run the global ctors, resulting in havoc, so it was simply forbidden to do so.

C on the other hand had no reason to forbid calling `main`, and it was always traditionally possible.

As for when it's useful, I would say "rarely". Most of the programs I've seen that called `main` were IOCCC entries.